# "==" for Strings always returning false

Tags: android, string, compare

I can't seem to get the code within the second if statement to execute. I have logged both values being compared and also ran the debugger and checked them. They are both "a". It always shows the incorrectPasswordDialog. This question seems difficult because it seems as though it should just work but any help is appreciated.

```
private void logUserIn(AppUser user) {
            if (user != null){
                Log.d("mPassword: ", mPassword);
                Log.d("user.getPassword(): ", user.getPassword());
                String userPassword = user.getPassword().toString();
                String formPassword = mPassword.toString();
                if ( userPassword == formPassword ){
                    Intent welcomePage = new Intent(this, StartScreenActivity.class);
                    welcomePage.putExtra("name", mName);
                    startActivity(welcomePage);
                }
                else {
                    showIncorrectPasswordDialog();
                }
            }else {
                showIncorrectUserNameDialog();
            }
        }
```

Comment: use String.equals(); or String.equalsIgnoreCase();

Comment: This isn't Android related, however Google on Java reference types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the object identity.  Use `string.equals()` to check for equivalence.

```
if(userPassword.equals(formPassword)){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ( userPassword == formPassword ){
```

to

```
if ( userPassword.equals(formPassword) ){
```

`==` compares object *references*, whereas `.equals` compared String *values*.

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare string using `==`
try like this

Compares the specified object to this string and returns true if they are equal. The object must be an instance of string with the same characters in the same order.

```
 if ( userPassword.equals(formPassword)){
    // do some stuff
  }
```

or

Compares the specified string to this string ignoring the case of the characters and returns true if they are equal.

```
 if(userPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(formPassword))
 {
     //do some stuff
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `JAVA` to compare between strings, you should use:

```
if(userPassword.equals(formPassword)) {
   // they are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ( userPassword == formPassword ){
```

to

```
if ( userPassword.equals(formPassword)){
```

In Java, `String` comparison is done with `.equals()`. Using `==` compares the object reference and not their values.

[Java String comparison](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2Fdata%2Fcomparestrings.html&ei=hj7CUunmGcmCygHalIDYDQ&usg=AFQjCNF3Z_YhX4OrkuIOLJ0fEULdanZSLA&sig2=KZ24sK7z5kdqdEEl0WQWqA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.aWc)

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA you should use equals to judge equal of value of different String.
== is used to judge object pointer for string, so it would only return false in your case.